# Auto font size for TextBlock?

Tags: wpf

I have a XAML form with a **TextBlock** object that is set to a width of 500 and a height of 150 (for example).

I'd like to figure out a way to have the font size change automatcally depending on the text assigned to the object, such that it's as big as possible without overflowing the assigned bounds. Including word wrap as necessary and possible so that the text fills the available space both horizontally and vertically.

In other words, if the text is "Star" it would use a font size of 40 but for "superstar" it might get set to 18.45, using smaller text so the entire width of the object gets used. (The font's normal aspect ratio must be maintained.)

My experimenting with using a **ViewBox** hasn't provided the desired results as yet.

Comment: "My experimenting with using a ViewBox hasn't provided the desired results as yet." Why not? That would be exactly the right approach. Set the Width and Height of the Viewbox of course, not the TextBlock.

Comment: My first approach was using a ViewBox and I'm not rejecting it as a solution just yet. I just haven't figured out the right settings for what I need. The main problem I've seen is one of wrapping. Even if wrapping is turned on in the TextBlock, the text ends up all on one line, even when there's plenty of vertical space left in the ViewBox.

Comment: So you also want the text to wrap? You should certainly mention that in your question, because it is an entirely different problem than what you have described so far.

Comment: Might be a different solution but not at all a different problem. The bottom line is that the text needs to be sized and wrapped to fit the space.

Comment: This is not a simple problem. I've implemented similar things in the past and the trick is finding the optimal wrapping / font size balance for a given string. Lots of manual calcs required. There is nothing build into to WPF that can do this.